# Non-selectable columns in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a table with multiple columns. I want content of each column to be selected individually. When I start selecting first column, second, third ... are automatically getting selected. When I select one column I want make other columns non selectable.

I have tried applying following class on elements and it worked fine in Firefox. No matter where you start selection from, its never selectable.

```
.unselectable {
    user-select: none; /* CSS3 */
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
}
```

For IE I have tried property called `unselectable="on"`, In Internet Explorer, it is still selectable if the selection starts outside. I want to prevent selection of certain columns even selection starts from outside.

I have tried using `onselectionstart` and `onmouseover` but as the selection is starting outside of element these are not getting triggered.

Do I have any hope ?

Comment: What is your purpose for selecting each column individually? I created a table with some text inside it and I selected the text without encountering your problem. Also can you please provide some more detail on why this is a problem? Could you give us a snippet or all of your code so we can test it?

Comment: Your best shot is probably selecting the table cells via jquery (easy and clean selectors) und set the corresponding css classes to change the behaviour. You may want to use the style-attribute instead, so these properties cannot be overwritten with custom user css files from browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that for now there is no pure CSS solution.

It may sound weird, but you could clone the content of the column you want the user to select into a separate table that will be `positioned: absolutely` over the original column.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel... check out http://www.datatables.net/

This is a JQuery table plug-in that'll knock your socks off.

It looks like it is already doing what you would like to do and it is free.

Comment: Datatables are wonderful :) they will simplify the task for you @Gopal indeed

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, and seems like a plug. -1

Answer (score 0):

It might help to include a TH with a SCOPE attribute. Can't say it will work, but it does make for a more semantic table. CSS can hook the attribute, so a DOM solution can't be that far off.